# In redmine, how can I efficiently postpone a set of tasks?

Tags: redmine

In my current project set up I have a version with a set due date. 
Now all the tasks for that version have an assigned start/end date (which in this specific case is the same day). 
E.g.

```
task x     -> due 20.3.
task y     -> due 21.3. 
task [...] -> due [...]
```

Now it could happen that I am not able to finish a certain task as planned on the given day.

The only option I found to postpone a set of tasks was to bulk edit the start/end date, which only gives me the option to set the same start/end date for all selected tasks. 
Is there a way to simply postpone a set of tasks by `amount x`?
E.g.:

```
task #1 -> due someday+x
...     -> ....
task #N -> due otherday+x
```

What would be the best approach for the problem described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue has been resolved, please see the redmine [forum](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/29494?r=29498) in case you're interested in the solution.

Comment: Please post your solution in your answer instead of just giving a link.

Comment: Do you know how old this question is?

It is honorable of you that you try and educate people, but it would be even nicer, if you would lead by example and simply improve upon my answer.

This would actually help the community.